# Stucked at billing Information section on checkout page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

Every time i try to continue the testing procedure for the checkout page i get stuck at the billing information. It says loading, but does not continue for the next section.

1. I'm using one page checkout
2. when i click inspect element and go to the network tab it is showing 1 js file which is jquery-1.10.2.min.map
3. The error returned is: "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function" in a js file called prototype.js
4. I'm using magento 1.9

Anyone can help on this ??
My website is www.925sterlingsilver.com.au

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Check your file permissions.

Comment: Try disabling any extensions that may be conflicting, probable js conflict

Comment: @TBIInfotech i deleted all the extensions except the M2E & the order eraser . thx

Comment: Just comment out them too, and check again

Comment: @TBIInfotech i did that, No difference mate . Thx

Comment: Cleared cache, after disabling, any other customization, try switching theme and use default theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured Out What's the problem the Prototype.js file had some errors, i believe because of the compression it lost some lines or something like that. anyway i downloaded a fresh copy of prototype.js and this solved the problem.

Thanks for every one who tried to help .
Harry

Answer (score 1):

Can't Comment, (not high enough reputation), but the function that is resulting in the error is in the opcheckout.js script, line 372, where the Ajax function is called that saves the billing information.

I would start by window.console.logging all of the parameters that are passed to that function before it is called so that you can diagnose the issue. My guess is that one of them has problems (is null or of the wrong type based upon your error).

When you revert to the base theme, does the problem still occur?

If not, do a comparison between the template files (likely `package/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` and/or `package/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`) with their base package counterparts to locate the differences, and hopefully the issue.

Comment: i tried to use the base/default theme but still the same problem occur ! thx

Answer (score 0):

have you used Mage::log() or echo in any one of the checkout related pages,
which might cause the stop loading if you write any wrong types in log or echo.

Comment: i didn't touch anything in the code, all what i did was pure CSS, i didn't even changed the class names, only attributes value was changed. Thx